# String to Milliseconds convertion in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a string that contains time
`timedata <- "08:39:41:759:520"` I want to convert this date string value into milliseconds format .

Note:
I have tried with following commands:
`as.POSIXct(timedata)`

It throws following error:
`Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

How do I solve it and convert data into milliseconds/microseconds format

Comment: can u say expected output? `unclass(as.POSIXlt(timedata, '%H:%M:%OS', tz='UTC'))` ,example : `options(digits.secs=6)   
Sys.time()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your input string first. I assume it is `hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds:microseconds`.

```
timedata <- "08:39:41:759:520"

#replace last two :
timedata <- gsub(":(?=\\d*$)", ".", 
     gsub(":(?=\\d*$)", "", 
          timedata, 
          perl = TRUE), 
     perl = TRUE)

#coerce to POSIXct and subtract current date
timedata <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(timedata, '%H:%M:%OS', tz='UTC')) - 
  as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()))

#this is a floating point number, print digits of interest (following digits can't be zero)
sprintf("%.6f",timedata)
#[1] "31181.759520"
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland . I just needed code for conversion without subtracting with current date . It worked fine for me Thanks a lot